# Extract last word from strings

Tags: google-sheets, split

In Google Sheets I have string values in cells like so:

> 1 Gheringhap Street, Geelong VIC 3220, Australia

I want to extract the country value from the string. The trouble is the string values have different numbers of commas so it's hard to say at which position the last value of the cell will be. I've tried:

```
=INDEX(SPLIT(A2, ","), 1, 3)
```

But that only works if there are exactly two commas, if there are more or less commas then the query fails.

Is there any other way to get the value of a string in a cell?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are many way to do so. One is to split on spaces and discard what is not required. Another is with a formula such as conventional in Excel (count the spaces by comparing the length of the string in full and after substituting spaces with nothing) and feed that as a parameter into a function that will skip to that instance in the string, but in Google Sheets the easiest way may be with [regexextract](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3098244?hl=en) eg:

```
 =REGEXEXTRACT(A1,".+\s(.+)")
```

This creates an extract group (inside the inner parentheses) of any character `.` any number of times `+` that follows after any character any number of times and then a space `\s`.

Replace `,` by `;` if that is what is required by the locale of your spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi, just have a small problem. What if the country name is "United States" or "Czech Republic", I only get "States" and "Republic" from this formula.

Comment: Ok, got something :)

=TRIM(REGEXEXTRACT(A1,".+\,(.+)"))

Comment: Just a word on internationalization: the "," in this formula (like in any formula) is replaced by the list delimiter (";" in my case, Hungary), which is set in regional settings.